# Saving to a database using a Nokogiri (json?) rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, nokogiri

RoR noob here! I have a rake task doing what I want to do I am just stuck on how to get the results saved to my `language` table. I want the results from this rake task to populate the values of the `language` field on my `language` table. I'm open to any suggestions (like using json here)

```
namespace :scraper do
  desc "Scraper"
  task scrape: :environment do

require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'
require 'json'

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers"
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))  
page.css('td b a').each do |line|
 puts line.text
end
end
```

Comment: Since you **have** used Rails for at least a **bit**, you **did** use ActiveRecord **at least** a little, right?

Comment: Yeah, I have an idea what to do, I was more or less seeking advice to see if I could use my current code as a basis to actually do it.

Comment: Yeah I know it doesn't, I don't know where I claimed to the contrary, I was just asking for help taking the next step of taking the results and putting them in my table (as Ravindra below has so graciously done below). I think you were too focused on being belittling and less on being helpful.

Comment: "if I could use my current code as a basis to actually do it" is a pretty solid clue. Regardless, my intent was driven by the fact that a self-found solution is more valuable. I don't mind anyone jumping in with a "ready-to-go" solution, but you're not the author of it. You didn't read up on relevant topics and you don't know the drawbacks of that code. That works fine for one-off tasks, but not for learning. That's just info for consideration, it's too late for anything else anyway.

Comment: Rails includes [`rails runner`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) which is designed to allow Ruby code to access the basic Rails stack without the HTML generation. That will supply you access to Active Record and everything it knows about your database, to connect to the database and to do the normal CRUD actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace :scraper do
  desc "Scraper"
  task scrape: :environment do
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'csv'
    require 'json'

    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers"
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))  
    page.css('td b a').each do |line|
      puts line.text  # "Spanish" 
      Language.create(language: line.text)
    end
  end
end
```